How to guarantee that the callback function is called after all the HTML is loaded inside contentDiv?
I have the following Javascript function which intends to load HTML and execute a callback function once the HTML has been loaded.
I would like to clarify if adding text to innerHTML guarantees that the elements will be available in the DOM.
Is the callback function called after all the elements loaded are ready in the DOM in this case or it might be the case it is not?
function loadView(viewId, callback) {

    let contentDiv = document.getElementById('content');
    let url = `${viewId}.html`; // Correctly construct the URL using template literals

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => {
            if (!response.ok) {
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
            return response.text();
        })
        .then(data => {
            // Append the fetched content to contentDiv
            contentDiv.innerHTML += data; 

            // Invoke the callback
            if (typeof callback === 'function') {
                callback();
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error loading content:', error);
        });

}


Assigning to .innerHTML is synchronous. It doesn't complete until everything has been added to the DOM. So your code should do what you want.
